# What's the difference between Crucial's Mac vs. non-Mac DDR3 SO-DIMM?

Tags: memory

Crucial has many part numbers of memory for different systems; however, it appears that, for example, part number for ThinkPad X230, [CT2946704](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/thinkpad-x230/CT2946704), is actually merely an alias for [CT2KIT102464BF160B](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/ct2kit102464bf160b).

However, it appears that Mac memory has an entirely different part number, [CT2K8G3S160BM](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/ct2k8g3s160bm); additionally, it appears that only the Mac memory is said to be lead and halogen free, in addition to being the only one for Mac.

Is there any actual difference between CT2KIT102464BF160B and CT2K8G3S160BM?  Both seem to be CL=11 and 1.35V otherwise (although, IIRC, at least the PC one is supposed to be dual-voltage, although their pages don't seem to mention that anymore).

Basically, although I'm sure the chips themselves are the same, it remains unclear what actual differences there are to warrant a separate part number.  Perhaps someone did some kind of comparison of the information stored with the SPD chips of these Crucial modules?

Comment: The Mac memory is even rated to be compatible with thinkpads as well. My hypothesis is that it is important for Mac users to very clearly state that the product is compatible, because most aren't. Therefore there must exist a Mac memory variant. However, calling something Mac memory makes it sound like it isn't compatible with other laptops. Therefore there is both Mac memory and non-Mac memory even though the modules are identical. Note that I have no sources for this claim, it is just my hypothesis.

Comment: I'd like to point out that, effectively, the question is about whether the information on the SPD chips between these modules differs.  http://mdoc.su/o/spdmem.4 http://bxr.su/OpenBSD/sys/dev/spdmem.c http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_presence_detect

Answer (score 5):

Good question. The short answer is that there is no difference in performance, since both will work. I know because I bought the same exact "non-Mac" kit, and I've had no problems with it. From a technical perspective, there isn't a difference between the kits. As to whether the "non-Mac" kits contain halogen and lead, I can't verify, but it shouldn't affect performance.

I don't have both modules, so I can't check what the differences are (if any). Most likely, it's just marketing from Crucial. The "Mac" version retails for an additional $10, so those who aren't tech savvy might be inclined to go for them, but otherwise they're the same thing. You can find more info on the types of supported memory for each model on Apple's support pages - this is the one for the iMacs: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205040. As long as the memory you're getting matches the specifications defined by Apple for your model, you should be all set.

Comment: I disagree that Mac memory is 10$ more expensive; in fact, I specifically bought Mac memory for my ThinkPad, because it was more like 10$ cheaper.

Comment: Also, what do you mean, "no difference in performance, since both will work"? Since both ThinkPad and MacBook "work", is there also no difference in performance between the two different laptops?

Comment: Performance difference in the memory, memory running at specific frequency isn't going to differ between different modules